# Will cutting a 50m CAT6 cable in half achieve a gigabit connection?

Tags: layer1, cable, cabling, speed, utp

I have a new CAT6 cable that's 50 metres long and only performs at 100 megabit. I've tested it in a variety of gigabit ports and it never allows a gigabit connection. Is it the length that's the problem and will cutting it in half to make two 25 metre cables make it perform at gigabit speeds ? i.e. is the length likely the problem or is it just a duff cable ?

Comment: If it's a **new** prefab cable, then take it back and tell them it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I already got a refund but they said I could keep it anyway. It was an eBay item which probably relates to the poor quality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cat6 can provide Gigabit speeds up to 90+ meters.

It is far more likely that one of the terminations is the problem.  Gigabit requires the use of all 8 wires, so if one (or both) of the terminations isn't making good contact, then it could run at 100M which only requires 4 wires.

Comment: The cable is machine made and has moulded RJ45 connectors which I guess could be faulty. So you suggest I should replace the RJ45 on each end ?

Comment: You can try if you like, but it is more difficult to terminate a Cat6 properly than Cat5/5e. It could also be a problem with the cable itself.  If you have access to a cable tester, I would try reterminating but if not, I would probably just replace the cable.